# Get one by id with SQL and .net using AJAX

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

I have this part of an app where I need to pull information from a table on SQL Server and print it in a view when I press a button, using AJAX. I have an api connection to the DB and Im using entity framework and an automapper with it.

Heres my controller from the frontside of the app:

```
    {
        string baseurl = "https://localhost:44387";
        // GET: Asociacion

        public async Task<ActionResult> GetOne(int? id)
        {

            Asociacion aux = new Asociacion();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("dinadeco/Asociacion/GetOneById?id=" + id);

                if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var auxRes = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    aux = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Asociacion>(auxRes);
                }
            }
            return View(aux);
        }
    }
```

Heres the view I have so far, Ive never really used AJAX also its a really big table, here it is:

```
@model Front.DO.Asociacion

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetOne";
}

<h2>GetOne</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Asociacion</h4>
    <hr />

    <td>
        <input type="text" id="searchField" name="searchFieldText" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" style="color:black;background-color:rgb(216, 214, 208)" value="Search" onclick="submitClick()" />
    </td>

    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.estado)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.estado)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.activo_import)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.activo_import)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ano)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ano)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tipo_id)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tipo_id)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nombre)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.nombre)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nombre_antes)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.nombre_antes)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.representante_id)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.representante_id)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.titulo)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.titulo)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.region_id)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.region_id)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.provincia_id)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.provincia_id)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.canton_id)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.canton_id)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.distrito_id)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.distrito_id)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.domicilio)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.domicilio)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.telefono)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.telefono)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fax)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fax)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.email)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.web)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.web)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.not_fax)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.not_fax)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.not_email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.not_email)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.not_func_regional)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.not_func_regional)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fecha_asamblea)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fecha_asamblea)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.notas)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.notas)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.es_cemento)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.es_cemento)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fecha_registro)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fecha_registro)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fecha_constitucion)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fecha_constitucion)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tomo)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tomo)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.folio)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.folio)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.asiento)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.asiento)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ultimo)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ultimo)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>

<script>
    function submitClick() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "dinadeco/Asociacion/GetOne?id=" + $('#searchField').val(),
            type: "GET",

        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Is there an error?

Comment: The view shows correctly and everything seems fine, but when I press the button it doesnt show the info in the view, it just kinda refreshes the view with empty info again.

Comment: Did you check the javascript console for messages? Have you tried to hit the API directly with a browser or Postman? What help we can give is very limited without knowing what is going on at runtime. Debug the code and observe the execution and the variables.

Comment: Will do, thank you very much. I think youre right, I might have an issue with the API.